# Footnote in revtex4

Tags: footnotes, revtex

Can somebody explain to me how to make a footnote in revtex4, so that it is placed on the same page as text and not in the bibliography?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) If you are using `revtex4` to submit a paper to a journal, then I don't think you should try to modify this: the footnotes are placed with the bibliography becomes the journal wants it to be so. Otherwise you can use the `nofootinbib` option (see the answer by cgnieder below).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`revtex4` has an option `nofootinbib` (presumably this will change *all* footnotes):

```
\documentclass[nofootinbib]{revtex4}

\textheight=2in %just for this example
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{book,
author  = "Arnold Author",
title   = "Book title",
year    = "2012"
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
Some text\footnote{With a footnote} and a citation~\cite{book}.

\bibliography{\jobname.bib}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Yes,but I'm finishing my thesis that has been written in the form of an article.Is there any other solution to my problem within \documentclass[11pt,article]{revtex4} ?

Comment: If i use `\documentclass[11pt,article]{revtex4}` I get `LaTeX Warning: Unused global option(s): [article].` which means there is no `article` option?! Other than that: why not `\documentclass[11pt,article,nofootinbib]{revtex4}`

Comment: It works!(\documentclass[11pt,article,nofootinbib]{revtex4})I just hope it won't alter anything else in my work.Thanks,you've saved me from loosing few more hours.